# How do I change status from "Pending" to "Completed"?

Tags: 6, ubercart

Ubercart is install without any payment gateway. The workflow is to take user orders via out website and payments are handled offline. Once we received payment and shipped the product, we'd like to mark the order as Completed.

Here is the [doc](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/developer/920/order_states_and_statuses):

> 1. When a customer moves from the checkout form to the review order page, a new order is created with their information in the default
>      status for the in_checkout state. (By default, this is "In checkout.")
> 2. When a customer completes checkout, the order gets moved from the default in_checkout status to the default status for the post_checkout
>      state. (By default, this is "Pending.")
> 3. The rest happens manually by order administrators, but the other two default statuses are "Processing" and "Completed." Processing is
>      actually just another status in the post_checkout state while
>      Completed is the default status for the completed state.

However, I don't see a status dropdown list or similar UI element for changing an order's status when editing an existing order:

> http://shop.example.com/admin/store/orders/100001/edit

How can I change the status from `Pending` to `Completed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the drupal 7version of Ubercart 3, order status would be changed using the dropdown found under

`http://shop.example.com/admin/store/orders/100001/view`

Answer (score 0):

We update status in

Home » Administration » Store » Orders

or:

admin/store/orders/view

At that interface, we see four icons.  If you hover over them you will see:

- View order <order#>
- Print order <order#>
- Edit order <order#>
- Delete order <order#>

Click on **View order <order#>**

The URL should now read:

admin/store/orders/<order#>/view

At the bottom of that screen you should see a drop down labeled:

**Order status**

with **Completed** as the last choice

Select the status you want, indicate whether or not you want a copy (good for troubleshooting and records) and then click on **Update**.